# .NET upgrade to a server with lower version

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

We are upgrading a project from .NET-Framework Version 3.0 to 4.5. The upgrade of the code was successful and now we plan to publish the app to our servers.

Our concern:

The server has only .NET-Framework Version 4.0-Version installed and not Version 4.5.

Will this be an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

This will be definitively a problem.

The .NET-Runtime Version 4.0 cannot execute .NET 4.5-Code.

You should be aware of that the [support-timeframe](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/gp/framework_faq/en-us) for .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 will end on January 12, 2016. Consider to upgrade your code and your server at least to .NET 4.5.2.